# JMS JNDI properties for JBoss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: jboss, cast-iron

when i gave this credentials in **ibm websphere cast iron**, the server said "the server is not connecting".

always it says connecting to endpoint. but its not connected. i bored to wait for more than one hour[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Contexts-Obtaining_a_Context_using_InitialContext.html) documentation. JNDI client configuration should be the same between JBoss AS 4 & 5 so don't worry that the docs are for JBoss AS 5.

To be clear, the JNDI client configuration is the same regardless of what you're looking up (e.g. JMS connection factory, database connection pool, etc.).

Comment: I gave this. But it's not connected.

Comment: Do you have any additional information (e.g. a stack-trace)? Just saying "it's not connected" doesn't provide enough detail to determine what the actual problem is.

Comment: i had updated my question with an image  @Justin Bertram